# How do I generate pretty JSON with json4s?

Tags: scala, json4s

This snippet of code works very well, but it generates compact JSON (no line breaks / not very human readable).

```
import org.json4s.native.Serialization.write
implicit val jsonFormats = DefaultFormats

//snapshotList is a case class
val jsonString: String = write(snapshotList)
```

Is there an easy way to generate pretty JSON from this?

I have this workaround but I'm wondering if a more efficient way exists:

```
import org.json4s.jackson.JsonMethods._
val prettyJsonString = pretty(render(parse(jsonString)))
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
import org.json4s.jackson.Serialization.writePretty

val jsonString: String = writePretty(snapshotList)
```

Comment: For me import statement should've been: `import org.json4s.jackson.Serialization.writePretty`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ObjectMapper [`writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter` function](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.5/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html#writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter()):

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
val pretty = mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter()
                   .writeValueAsString(jsonString));
```

This returns a `ObjectWriter` object from which you can get a pretty-formatted string.

Comment: I tried this approach but I'm getting an exception:

`java.lang.ClassCastException: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectWriter cannot be cast to scala.runtime.Nothing$`

Do you know why?

It's strange because I looked at the source code of the pretty() method and it does basically exactly what you suggested.

Comment: Here's my test code:

`import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper`
`import org.json4s._`
`import org.json4s.jackson.JsonMethods._`

`val jsonString = """{"price": 10.8}"""`
`val json = parse(jsonString)`

`val mapper = new ObjectMapper()`
`mapper.writeValueAsString(json) //this works`
`val writer = mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter() //this throws exception`
`val prettyJsonString = writer.writeValueAsString(json)`